# Passing a raw argument in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, parameters, arguments

I am passing a argument, but i am getting a syntax error can anyone help me to find a way to do this?

I cannot seem to assign string to the numpy array so i tried to convert them into numbers.

```
import numpy
def who_is_winner(pieces_position_list):
    import numpy as np
    array = np.zeros((6,7))
    A, B, C, D, E, F, G = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
    for x in pieces_position_list:
        _list = x.split("_")
        #print(int(_list[0])) --> not working either
        for y in range(6,  -1, -1):
            if array[y, _list[0] != 0:
                     #array[y, _list[0]] = _list[1] --> syntax error
                     pass
            
                     
who_is_winner(["A_Red",
                          "B_Yellow",
                          "A_Red",
                          "B_Yellow",
                          "A_Red",
                          "B_Yellow",
                          "G_Red",
                          "B_Yellow"])
```

Comment: Add `pass` after `if array[y, _list[0] != 0:`.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work :/

Comment: You missed a close bracket in `array[y, _list[0]`

Comment: @jasonwong i get this error now ```IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices```

Comment: how do i typecast this properly?

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy
def who_is_winner(pieces_position_list):
    import numpy as np
    array = np.zeros((6,7))
    A, B, C, D, E, F, G = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
    for x in pieces_position_list:
        _list = x.split("_")
        #print(int(_list[0])) --> not working either
        for y in range(6,  -1, -1):
            if array[y, _list[0]] != 0:
                #array[y, _list[0]] = _list[1] --> syntax error
                pass
                
who_is_winner(["A_Red","B_Yellow","A_Red","B_Yellow","A_Red","B_Yellow","G_Red","B_Yellow"])
```

Write **pass** after if statement and add "]" after [y, _list[0] to avoid errors.
This would again give an error `` IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices `` because in `who_is_winner(["A_Red","B_Yellow","A_Red","B_Yellow","A_Red","B_Yellow","G_Red","B_Yellow"])` all arguments are string while they should be **integer**.

Comment: Is there a proper way to typecast this? Can you understand what i am trying to do?

Comment: Try converting String to int, i guess so.